# Get list of joined rows with DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi

I have `Supplier` dimension table has 1:n relationship with `InvoiceDetail` fact table. I would like to get the list of *active* suppliers like below SQL, but in DAX language:

```
SELECT [Id]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Code]
  ,[CountryIso]

FROM [Supplier] s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [InvoiceDetail] id WHERE s.id = id.SupplierId)
```

I am not sure how I can do on Measure with DAX

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that an active supplier means that the supplier has an invoice against them and that your data looks something like this..

Invoice Table

[image: Invoice Table]

Supplier Table

[image: Supplier Table]

Creating a relationship between the two tables will in effect, 'join' the two tables.

[image: Joining the Tables]

You can then use invoice number field from the invoice table and the name/code/countryiso from the supplier table.

Example being:

[image]

The value are only being drawn from the invoice table, so you'll only see active Invoices.

If being an active supplier means having a true bool value, join the tables and add a report/page wide filter on that bool value.